# Complement of a compact set in the Riemann sphere has countable many components.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am reading Walter Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis", and he states that given $P \subset \mathbb{C}$ a compact set, and $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ the Riemann sphere, the complement of $P$ in  $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ (i.e. $ \hat{\mathbb{C}} -P$) has at most countable many components.

How can I prove this? It probably is pretty trivial since Rudin skips over the proof of the statement but I cannot seem to prove it.

I have tried covering  $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ with the connected components and a neighborhood of $P$. Then supposing you have an uncountable amount of components, tried get to a contradiction using the compactness of  $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$.

But, how can I find a neighborhood of $P$ such that it does not cover an infinite amount of components? 
I am thinking in cases like when $P$ is a Cantor Space.

Because the Cantor Set in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact and its complement in the real line has uncountable many connected components.

So, it leaves me thinking what if $P$ behaves in a way that given any neighborhood $V$ of $P$, then $V$ covers an uncountable amount of connected components of  $\hat{\mathbb{C}}-P$? 
 Cannot think of any case that does, but cannot also negate that there is not such a case.

Any tips would be nice, Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The complement of the cantor set in $\mathbb{R}$ has countably many components: 2 of infinite length, 1 of length $\frac{1}{3}$, 2 of length $\frac{1}{9}$, 4 of length $\frac{1}{27}$, ...

Comment: Hint: the complement is open, so its connected components are also open (possibly using that $\mathbb{C}$ is locally connected), therefore each contains some element of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$.

Comment: Right...my mind went: non-countable and locally disconnected, then the complement must have non-countable components, but you are right. its very easy to see what you mean geometrically.

Comment: You can also go the way of assuming there are uncountably many connected components of the complement and working with the fact that every uncountable set in $\mathbb{C}$ has a limit point.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler, thanks, its so simple now that you mentioned it.

Answer (score 4):

Take one point in the complement of your compact set off the sphere and identify the punctured sphere with $\mathbb{R}^2$ via a homeomorphism. There you can say that the complement of a compact set is open, and each connected component therefore contains at least one point with rational coordinates. Therefore there is an injection from the connected-components of your complement to $\mathbb{Q}^2$ which is countable.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I wrote this a bit too fast.

Answer (score 3):

As manifolds are locally connected, components of open sets ( like the complement of compact sets) are open. And disjoint families of open sets in a separable space are at most countable.